# Get latest record and group with highest date - LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have table `Billing` as below

```
AccoundID | Group | DateOfBill
1234      | A     | 2017-07-12
1234      | B     | 2017-07-16
1234      | C     | 2017-07-31
1235      | A     | 2017-07-31
1236      | B     | 2017-07-31
```

As you see, `AccountID` 1234 have made 3 transaction on July 2017. So I need a list where the `AccountID` 1234 must be in `Group` C because that's is latest date on that transaction.

Here is my code snippet

```
var LatestAccount = from n in Billing
                    where (n.Group == "A" || n.Group == "B" || n.Group == "C")
                    group n by new { n.AccountID, n.Group } into g
                    select new { 
                        AccountId = g.Key.AccountID, 
                        Group = g.Key.Group , 
                        DateOfBill = g.Max(t => t.DateOfBill) 
                    };
```

But the result is wrong. How to do in LINQ?

Comment: You're grouping by the account Id and the group. You want to only group by account Id in your use case

Comment: Why don't you post how end result should look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Billing> Billings = new List<Billing>()
        {
            new Billing()
            {
                AccountID = 1234, DateOfBill = new DateTime(2017,07,12), Group = "A"

            },
            new Billing()
            {
                AccountID = 1234, DateOfBill = new DateTime(2017,07,16), Group = "B"

            },
            new Billing()
            {
                AccountID = 1234, DateOfBill = new DateTime(2017,07,31), Group = "C"

            },
            new Billing()
            {
                AccountID = 1235, DateOfBill = new DateTime(2017,07,31), Group = "A"

            },
            new Billing()
            {
                AccountID = 1236, DateOfBill = new DateTime(2017,07,31), Group = "B"

            }               
        };

        var LatestAccount = from n in Billings
                            where (n.Group == "A" || n.Group == "B" || n.Group == "C")
                            group n by new { n.AccountID } into g
                            select g.Where(d => d.DateOfBill == g.Max(m => m.DateOfBill)).Select(x => new { AccountId = g.Key.AccountID, Group = x.Group, DateOfBill = x.DateOfBill }).FirstOrDefault();

        foreach (var item in LatestAccount)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("AccountID: " + item.AccountId + "  Date of Bill: " + item.DateOfBill + "  Group: "+ item.Group);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
class  Billing
{
    public int AccountID { get; set; }
    public string Group { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBill { get; set; }
}
```

Is below what you want? 
If you show me the output you want, I can modify my answer.

[image]

Comment: Yes exactly this what I looking for

Comment: Please accept my reply as correct answer if it worked for you- so that other users can benefit: from knowing that the answer works and by having the question marked as Answered.
Please let me know if my answer worked for you or if you have any issues with the answer.